# Fill a timestamp column from substring info sql

Tags: sql, string, timestamp, h2

I have a table  MyTable defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (id SERIAL   NOT NULL, description VARCHAR, date TIMESTAMP)
```

In this table, `description` was filled with strings such as "TOP_XXXXXXXXXXXXX.tsp" where the 13 character long "XXX" is the value of the timestamp that should be in the `date` column. The `date` column, however, was not or incorrectly filled in.

I want to make an SQL statement to fill `date` column with the correct values, parsed from the `description` column. I use H2 database.

Comment: use SUBSTRING function http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#substring

Comment: Thx for your comment. The most problematic part for me is actually the syntax of the update table

Comment: I think in this way: update MyTable set date = cast(substring(description, 4, 13) as datetime) where date is null (I suppose you have NULL that column until the UPDATE command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET [date] = CAST(SUBSTR([description], 4, 13) AS DATETIME)
```